# Indicate command line activation successfully completed UWP

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp, command-prompt, windows-10-universal

I am working on a text-editor app that can be activated via command line. The argument provided is treated as path to file, i.e. `pad` launches the app but `pad "C:\Sample.txt"` launches the app and then displays the "Sample.txt" file. This works well in command prompt, but in power-shell after command is executed, the execution completes only after the app is closed. Also, the execution is recorded as failed. Is there any way I can notify the command to be completed successfully from my app itself??

Example of the difference in command line activation of Windows Terminal in both command prompt and power-shell:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15gBiCcio3feGwxappgyBm68lezK5I0t2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know. But you can have a look at similar project: https://github.com/JasonStein/Notepads

Comment: I have looked at this app and it has the same issue too.

Comment: @postanote I am showing Windows Terminal as an example to how the commandline activation differs in powershell and cmd. Same behavior can be observed in any uwp app that implements appexecutionalias. This has nothing to do with PSCore, Windows Terminal settings.

Comment: Look into the `Start-Process` command, when running exes just like that vs with `&` or `Start-Process`, you may get different results

Comment: Thanks @Neko Musume, it works fine when typing command manually. But if I set the editor app default in git, git always registers opening of document to be failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing cmd.exe vs powershell.exe uwpapp starts. Remember the cmd.exe simply does not hold/wait for the process/exe it started, whereas PowerShell does for uwp at least, by design.

As a workaround, if you want the PowerShell consolehost to immediately be available for more interactive steps, then you can use jobs to simulate what you are seeing when using cmd.exe. So, from a WT PowerShell session...

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {wt}
```

Comment: Is there any way an uwp app can indicate powershell that process has started and not to wait any more?? And what about when the uwp app exits powershell indicates that the command run failed??

Comment: Nope, PS already knows it started the app and has a session handle to that app, hence your original deal, before the Start-Job reference to make PS usable while the job is running. The child app won't know about the parent. The child app must report back its error/exit code to the calling parent, thus the parent cannot be closed until it receives the error/exit code. That is what you are seeing in the parent, PS in this case. If you really want to see what a command/script is doing/calling/initializing, etc., you can use normal debug tools. See Trace-Command, Start-trace, etc.